# Angular string interpolation issue when using external library

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm creating an Angular 6 app and am getting some bizarre behaviour with string interpolation.

In the code snippet below I'm defining an observable and then subscribing to it. Everything is working fine, all of the console.log statements are saying what they should, but for some reason, the string interpolation I have in my HTML file isn't updating.  I have `{{myString}}` placed in a simple h3 tag and it doesn't automatically update even though the variable itself is being correctly set. It's as if the change isn't being detected.  I did some reading and came across some material that suggested certain types of calls can go outside the 'zone' of angular detection but the material quickly got above my IQ level.

Any input advice would be appreciated.

```
ngOnInit() {
    const myObservable = Observable.create((observer: Observer<string>) => {
      qrcode.callback = res => {
        observer.next(res);
        observer.complete();
      };
    });
    myObservable.subscribe((data: string) => {
      this.myString = data;
      console.log(data);
      console.log('myString value: ' + this.myString);
      if (this.myString == 'It works!') {
        console.log('The value was successfully matched');
      } else {
        console.log('The value did not match');
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Any chance you can post complete code where issue can be reproduced?

Comment: this might be helpful https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: Yo could it be that you close the observable before the date gets through ? Like the complete somehow gets called before next

Comment: Thanks so much to all of you who responded. The ChangeDetectorRef solution did the trick, and I also read up on some of the other lifecycle hooks per some of the other comments on this thread. Thanks again folks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import ChangeDetectorRef

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

Inject and instantiate it

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { 
}
```

Finally mark for check after setting the myString value so the changes take place

```
this.ref.markForCheck();
```

Comment: Thanks so much to all of you who responded.  The ChangeDetectorRef solution did the trick, and I also read up on some of the other lifecycle hooks per some of the other comments on this thread.  Thanks again folks.

Answer (score 0):

Please use lifecycle hooks like `ngDoCheck()` or `ngAfterViewInit()` if you explicitly want to perform change detection based on your requirement.

`ngOnInit()` is executed once on app load and code inside it will not be executed by Angular unless you reload the app.

Comment: Well but subscribing to an observable in the ngOnInit is a standard practice

Comment: Yes but custom change detector can impact app performance if not handled carefully. It's best to avoid that if possible.

Comment: what has subscribing to an observable in the ngOnInit to do with with the custom change detector ? ngOnInit only gets called once and you can and should use some lifecycle interfaces. How do you react to an Input binding change other than in the ngOnChanges without creating messy code ?